# generating function for $\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$

Tags: generating-functions

How to construct generating function such that 
$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n)!} t^n $$

Comment: Woops!!, it seems to be related to $e^{x^2}$. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html should have googled property :/??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to consider the exponential generating function in this case. 
\begin{align}
a_{n} &= \frac{n!}{(2n)!} \\
f(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, \frac{t^{n}}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{n}}{(2n)!} = \cosh(\sqrt{t}).
\end{align}

Linear generating function:
\begin{align}
g(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, t^{n} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1)_{n} \, (1)_{n} \, t^{n}}{n! \, (1)_{2n}} = 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(1)_{n} \, t^{n}}{n! \, \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{n}} = {}_{1}F_{1}\left(1; \frac{1}{2}; \frac{t}{4}\right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{\sqrt{\pi \, t}}{2} \cdot e^{\frac{t}{4}} \cdot erf\left(\frac{\sqrt{t}}{2}\right).
\end{align}

---

Equation (21) of [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) is as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!} &= \frac{1}{t} \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n+1} \, (n+1)! \, t^{2n+2}}{(2n+2)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{t} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n} \, n! \, t^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\
&= \frac{1}{t} \, \left[ -1 + g(2 t^{2}) \right] \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cdot e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}} \cdot erf\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: no no .. you are making too complicated, I don't understand hypergeometric funtions. could you simply provide hints (even on comments) to arrive at eq (21) on this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Comment: @MulaKoSaag equation (21) has been demonstrated

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x)=1+e^{x/4}\frac{\sqrt{\pi x}}{2} \mbox{erf}(\sqrt{x}/2).$$

Comment: could you provide some hints to come at eq(21) on this page? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way, I'm afraid... My suggestion would be to write the well-known [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) expansions for both the exponential and error function, where that of the latter can be found by integrating the former term by term, and then employ the dreadful [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) formula for their multiplication.

Comment: Sorry, it's $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \frac{x^{-1/2}}{1+2x}dx$$. I didn't put it correctly. :( any hints? I got this result form equation (2) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html and Reflection formula.

Comment: @MulaKoSaag: Substitute $x=t^2$, and then insert an extra parameter *a* in the exponent. Notice that the new integral satisfies the differential equation $I(a)-2I'(a)=\sqrt{\dfrac\pi a}$